# React Native: Deep linking opening Facebook post on fb app using fbid

Tags: react-native

I am able to open Facebook page using `` Linking.openURL(`fb://page/${pageId}`); ``

I'm just wondering if it's possible to open a **Facebook post** using `Linking`.
I've tried using different schemes like

An example URL from a post in a browser:
`https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=834708294690078&set=a.207012927459621`

```
fb://post/834708294690078
fb://photo?fbid=834708294690078
```

None of these works

Is Linking on Facebook limited to only profiles and pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply open the web URL like this. Do not have to use any schemes.

```
Linking.openURL("https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=834708294690078&set=a.207012927459621")
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that it can redirect to the app using just URL. Thanks!